# Text with textAlign:justify has weird space at the end

Tags: react-native

I have a Text component with a lot of text inside. I want to set textAlign: "justify" to the content but a weird space is added after the component. I'm sure no styles are applied to add the space in my code.

[image]

It happens on both IOS and Android, but the space is too big in Android.

[Snack working example](https://snack.expo.dev/t60dzbC9O)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove the `textAlign: 'justify',`from paragraph style, it still works with the same style and no errors.

you can use the following:

```
<WebView
    source={{ html: "<p style='text-align: justify;'>Justified text here</p>" }}
/>
```

Comment: I need the text to be justified

Comment: Thank you, but that was a hack for older versions (API level < 26)

Comment: yes, i know that. the 'justify' is only supported for api >= 26

Comment: yes, I'm working with apiLevel=29. Justify works, but it adds a lot of space at the end (yellow in the image I've posted, or you can check my example on your phone).

Comment: i don't know actually, why it gave me that style with space, i will work to find the reason, but simply, adding marginBottom:'-25%' to the text, solves the problem

Comment: But if the text is dynamic, setting an static margin is not the right choice...

Comment: okay, i think one solution now is to devide the whole text component to multiple text components. i mean each paragraph is at a single text component

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the value 'justify' is only supported on Oreo (8.0) or above (API level >= 26). The value will fallback to left on lower Android versions. So remove the justify prop from textAlign.

Check this: [React native Text props: textAlign](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalign)

Comment: I have a higher API level, just a weird space added at the end.

Comment: @Ariel If you want to just add space between each sentence? Why don't you try using the lineHeight prop

Comment: I just want to remove that weird space at the end (yellow in the image I've posted)

Comment: remove the textAlign:"justfiy", and use the lineHeight prop if you want to have spaces between each line.